# Is there a way to correctly use com.android.volley.Response.Listener without incurring abstract class error

Tags: java, android-studio-3.4

I am following android developer tutorial on sending a simple HTTP request: https://developer.android.com/training/volley/simple

I am getting error: 'Listener is abstract; cannot be instantiated'

I have looked at https://afzaln.com/volley/com/android/volley/Response.Listener.html
and
https://afzaln.com/volley/com/android/volley/Response.html

Which describes Response class and Listener interface.  There is no mention of an abstract class.  I should be able to instantiate a new Listener as long as required methods are included. Correct?

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button getQuoteBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.getQuoteBtn);
        getQuoteBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                RequestQueue quoteQue = new Volley.newRequestQue(this);
                String quoteUrl = "http://quotes.rest/qod.json?category=inspire";
                StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, quoteUrl, new Response.Listener<String>()) {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {

                    }
                }
```

The line in question is:
new Response.Listener())

is underlined in red with Error message: Listener is abstract, cannot be instantiated.

There is no mention of this in the afformentioned android tutorial.

Additional info:
Documentation is confusing me.  Every tutorial on this subject show instantiation new Response.Listener.  I get why it doesnt work, confused as to why it is documented incorrectly multiple times, unless there were changes, which brings me to this:

when trying to create an instance, the intellisense auto populates type: errorListener in the third parameter of StringRequest.

StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, quoteUrl, errorListnener: Response.Listener rl = new...........

According to https://afzaln.com/volley/com/android/volley/toolbox/StringRequest.html

there are two StringRequest constructors, one with signature 3, another with 4. It looks like only one of those are available to me.

Is there an example of how to instantiate the Listener?

Comment: `Response.Listener<String>()` is an interface, and you will want to study any tutorial on interfaces and abstract classes, since it is a given that you can't simply initialize these with `new Foo()`, but rather the abstract type needs to be initialized with an instance of a concrete child class. One possible solution is to create an anonymous inline class, just as you're currently doing with your `OnClickListener()`. In fact, why not simply do this, just as you're already doing it?

Comment: Completely misread the answer due to being too far in the weeds. After enabling edit source, and seeing the Class and Interface, it now makes sense. Thanks for the answer.